# Generating a shorter ID with MongoDB and spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have an entity that is being saved with a MongoRepository.  The class has a property Id annotated with @Id:

```
public class KCItem {

    @Id
    private String id;
```

When saved it generates a long id - 5bb390b88ba5b9248ad148ce.  These ids will be part of URLs and I'd like them to be shorter (I don't expect to have more than 1 million total items).  What would be a better way to either replace Id with a shorter value OR create a second attribute that is the short id?

Comment: While projecting you can use any part of the objectID as it contains many information like the process id , timestamp etc

Comment: Is there a general consensus on which parts would make the "most unique"  I can tell the first byte (2 chars) are least useful, but beyond that it would seem like I could take the next 8 and be pretty likely to be OK in a system that isn't generating a ton of concurrent documents.